# Como pasar el foco de un text box a otro con un button en un form

Tags: c#

Hola mi problema es que tengo que cambio ir el foco entre dos text box al presionar un botón

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox2.Focused)
    {
        textBox1.Focus();
    }
    else if (textBox1.Focused)
    {
        textBox2.Focus();
    }      
}
```

Intente poner una condición

Por lo que investigue es fácil de resolver con el key press pero no puedo utilizarlo sólo lo debo hacer con el botón

Comment: que has probado? Has investigado alguna cosa? Tal i como está tu pregunta probablemente acabará cerrada por ser poco especifica y no mostrar ninguna prueba que hayas hecho ni ningun error en específico. Te recomiendo que modifiques la pregunta y añadas lo que hayas probado para que los demas usuarios tengan claro realmente que es lo que se pregunta y que te puedan dar una buena respuesta

Comment: Ya la edite lo mejor que pude perdón si no es muy legible pero soy nuevo

Comment: Sigo sin ver cual es el problema, este codigo que pones está bien, lo único que si ninguno de los 2 textbox tiene focus, al pulsar el botón no hará nada, pero si uno de los 2 textbox tiene focus y pulsas el botón te debería de funcionar correctamente tal y como lo tienes.

Comment: Él problema es que siempre se queda en uno de los textbox y no pasa al siguiente porque primero pondrá focus en el que no tiene y posterior a eso entra en el segundo if y como el focus cambia también se cumple entonces siempre se queda en uno de los dos

Comment: no has intentado con solo usar un if else si esta el texbox 1 seleccionado marcas el 2 si no marcas el 1

Answer (score 2):

Puedes jugar con la propiedad Tag de cada TextBox

```
//Formulario1
public Form1()
    {
        //inicia componentes
        InitializeComponent();
        //escribe en el tag del textbox1 el texto v
        textBox1.Tag = "v";
        //situa en foco en el textbox1
        textBox1.Focus();
        //situa en el tag del textbox2 el texto f
        textBox2.Tag = "f";
    }
    //al precionar el botón
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //si el tag del textbox1 tiene una v
        if (textBox1.Tag.Equals("v"))
        {
            //situa el focus en el textbox2
            textBox2.Focus();
            //escribe el texto v en el tag del textbox2
            textBox2.Tag = "v";
            //escribe el texto f en el tag del textbox1
            textBox1.Tag = "f";
        }
        //si en el tag del textbox1 no pone v y si lo pone en el textbox2
        else if (textBox2.Tag.Equals("v"))
        {
            //situa el foco en textbox1
            textBox1.Focus();
            //pone v en el tag del textbox1
            textBox1.Tag = "v";
            //pone f en el tag del textbox2
            textBox2.Tag = "f";
        }
    }
```